# How to tell someone politely that they have a wrong number?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, telephone-conversation

How can I tell someone politely that they have a wrong telephone number? I found this wording on [HowDoYouSay](http://www.howdoyousay.net/english-german/You_have_the_wrong_number/):

> Sie sind falsch verbunden.

Does it work? Are there any other ways of saying it?

Comment: Keep in mind that how you say this can make a big difference. (Der Ton macht die Musik.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it works. The most popular way to say this is:

> Sie haben sich verwählt.

An example dialogue:

> - Guten Tag, ich möchte bitte Jonas sprechen.
> - Wen? Jonas? Hier wohnt kein Jonas, **ich glaube, Sie haben sich verwählt**.

or:

> - Sie sind offensichtlich falsch verbunden.

or:

> - Anscheinend haben Sie eine falsche Nummer gewählt.

or:

> - Da liegt ein Irrtum vor.

Comment: *Anscheinend*, nicht *scheinbar* :)

Comment: Danke @CarstenS für die Korrektur. Ich tu mich schwer mit diesen Wörtern...

Comment: Regional wird aber umgangssprachlich *scheinbar/scheint's* dem korrekten *anscheinend* bevorzugt.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can say so, but it is a bit formal. The most common way to phrase it is with *verwählen*:

> Sie haben sich verwählt.

Both phrases are very blunt, though, and in essence tell the caller that they made a mistake. In order to make it more polite, you would add some uncertainty (even if you are indeed dead sure that they are wrong) and possibly add some excusatory phrases:

> Da sind Sie wohl falsch verbunden.
>   Da haben Sie sich anscheinend verwählt.
>   Oh, ich fürchte, da sind Sie falsch verbunden.
>   Oh, das tut mir leid, aber da haben Sie sich wohl verwählt.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, *falsch verbunden* is no longer correct. It applied to the olden days when one called the operator first and was *connected* to one’s partner. (In Germany, that was typically the job of the *Fräulein vom Amt*.) It could then have happened that these people accidentally connected the wrong lines which resulted in *falsch **verbunden.***

Nowadays, the technology-based connection mechanisms would not really allow a misconnection: You get the connection you dialed. So the better choice would be *verwählt* (misdialed).

However, many people will still use *falsch verbunden*. Remember to add polite filler words around it if you wish to be polite.

Comment: einspruch: eine verbindung besteht heute noch genauso wie früher, und man kann immernoch zur falschen person eine verbindung haben, nur passiert das nicht mehr wegen dem fräulein sondern wenn man einfach die falsche nummer eingegeben hat :)